# How to preserve the order in serializing JSON via MultipleChoiceField

Tags: django, django-serializer

I have a pre-defined list of valid choice:

```
allowed_choices = ['yes', 'no', 'I dont know']
```

I'm working on an API using the Django rest framework. To validate and serialize the inputs I'm using the Django Fields. For this purpose I have a chosen a `MulitpleChoiceField`.

```
dataColumns = serializers.MultipleChoiceField(
    choices=allowed_choices,
    allow_blank=False,
    source="data_Columns",
)
```

My view looks like this:

```
import json

# REST IMPORTS
from rest_framework import viewsets, response, status, serializers

# DJANGO IMPORTS
from django.http import HttpResponse


class TestSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    dataColumns = serializers.MultipleChoiceField(
        choices=allowed_choices,
        allow_blank=False,
        source="data_Columns",
    )


class TestViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def list(self, request):
        return response.Response(status=status.HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        return response.Response(status=status.HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)

    def update(self, request, pk=None):
        return response.Response(status=status.HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)

    def partial_update(self, request, pk=None):
        return response.Response(status=status.HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)

    def destroy(self, request, pk=None):
        return response.Response(status=status.HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = TestSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            try:

                print(serializer.validated_data.get("data_Columns"))

                json_return = json.dumps(["all good"])

                return HttpResponse(json_return,
                                    content_type='application/json')
            except:
                return HttpResponse(status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                                    content_type='application/json')
        else:
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(serializer.errors),
                                content_type='application/json',
                                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

If do an API call with the the following json input:

```
{
        "dataColumns": ["no", "yes"]
}
```

Then in the `validated_data` it prints `["yes", "no"]`. However the input was the other way around. My goal is to preserve this order. In reality the valid choices is a much bigger universe and I can't (want) the user to force my order.

Comment: Show us how you're using this and where the order isn't preserved. a MultipleChoiceField just allows for one choice, so it's not clear what order you're referring to.

Comment: @dirkgroten I've added more context. Hope this helps now. Please note that I'm new to this :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you mean with "it prints"? Where and how are your printing the list?

Comment: @HugoLuisVillalobosCanto see the print statement after the validation in the code. But even if I just return the validated data I get the wrong order

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my problem. If I use a `ListField` with child a `ChoiceField` then  the `to_internal_value` returns a `list` instead of a set (in the `MultipleChoiceField`). That means the order is preserved.

```
dataColumns = serializers.ListField(
    child=serializers.ChoiceField(
        choices=allowed_choices,
        allow_blank=False),
    source="data_Columns"
)
```